# Sax parsing raise error

Tags: android

I just pass to Sax parser but now i cant able to do that. what is the problem i dont understand.may be some minor mistake irritate me.
 this is my code :::

**Error::**

```
11-01 14:11:58.243: WARN/System.err(2327): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 203.119.105.55/WebServices/Service.asmx/GetRequest
11-01 14:11:58.243: WARN/System.err(2327):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:275)
11-01 14:11:58.243: WARN/System.err(2327):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:159)
11-01 14:11:58.243: WARN/System.err(2327):     at com.SAXParser1.SAXParser1.onCreate(SAXParser1.java:38)
11-01 14:11:58.243: WARN/System.err(2327):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-01 14:11:58.243: WARN/System.err(2327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-01 14:11:58.243: WARN/System.err(2327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-01 14:11:58.243: WARN/System.err(2327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-01 14:11:58.243: WARN/System.err(2327):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-01 14:11:58.243: WARN/System.err(2327):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 14:11:58.243: WARN/System.err(2327):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-01 14:11:58.253: WARN/System.err(2327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-01 14:11:58.253: WARN/System.err(2327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 14:11:58.253: WARN/System.err(2327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-01 14:11:58.253: WARN/System.err(2327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-01 14:11:58.253: WARN/System.err(2327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-01 14:11:58.253: WARN/System.err(2327):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Activity::**

```
try { 

    URL sourceUrl = new URL("URL");

    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

    Handler1 dataHandler = new Handler1();
    xr.setContentHandler(dataHandler);

    xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

    Dataset dataset = dataHandler.getParsednewJobdtl_DataSet();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sourceUrl"+sourceUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);



            RequestID  = dataset.getRequestID();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "RequestID"+RequestID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Status  = dataset.getStatus();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Status"+Status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            URL  = dataset.getURL();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "URL"+URL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            ActivityName = dataset.getActivityName();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ActivityName"+ActivityName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            AudioScript  = dataset.getAudioScript();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "AudioScript"+AudioScript, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);



       }catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Permission in manifest ::**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the response from the URL you are trying to get response.

After looking it, I am sure there is a problem in line:

```
URL  = dataset.getURL();
```

You are trying to parse the `<URL>` tag and error is there.

### Solution:

Try to mention the URL with `http://`

Comment: what is your side suggestion?

Comment: i have remove <URL> from field now i try and inform you

Comment: whats exactly the problem? I am sure you are not getting response from the mentioned URL or somewhat "http" kind of problem?

Comment: and also write external storage permission